# How to globally overload a operator with primitives in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, homebrew

I am trying to overload an operator globally with a function that takes two primitives (signed 32-bit ints), but my compiler gives me this error:

```
In file included from src/math.cc:31:0:
include/saturn/math.hh:38:34: error: 's32 operator/(s32, s32)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
 s32 operator /( s32 num, s32 den );
                                  ^
```

What I need is to be able to use the divide operator and have a function called—in this case, a BIOS function—which performs the division. Without this I presume the divide operators would not function, because my target CPU does not have instructions for division; my BIOS provides functionality for that.

I am targeting the Nintendo Game Boy Advance here using a GCC toolchain provided by devkitPro, and I cannot use their provided libraries for this task.

Comment: You cannot do this. _"Their provided libraries"_ may offer weak function entry points you can override at the linking stage.

Comment: you have to define yr own custom type and overload its divide

Comment: Assuming that you already have a C++ compiler for the CPU, I believe it should already perform division correctly, doesn't it?